# Python - retrieving a variable from memory?

Tags: python, variables, memory

I have two python scripts that need to communicate large variables to one another: python1.py and python2.py.

Let's say python1.py is running and has created a list variable 'x' which is very large. At the moment, I am saving (pickling) 'x' to the hard drive and then using subprocess to run python2.py which then loads up 'x' from the hard drive (I need to have two different python files because I am trying to parallelize a computation).

Is there an alternative, where I can call python2.py with an argument which is a pointer to memory, and then have python2.py create 'x' based on directly looking it up in the memory?

Comment: Are you using the generator script (which creates your `x` list) to launch the second script? How large is "very large"? Is the order important of the computation?

Comment: mmap should be able to do this. This article might help: http://blog.schmichael.com/2011/05/15/sharing-python-data-between-processes-using-mmap/

Comment: If this is linux, you could import python2 and use the multiprocessing module to fork into the function you want to run there. In linux, when you fork, you have the same memory so you don't need to serialize it. On windows, mp serializes anyway so no real benefit.

Comment: would recommend numpy arrays for this task: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yup, the generator script launches the 2nd script, order is not important, and large is about 50MB. I think mmap was what I was looking for, thanks Lanting. I am on windows and tried out multiprocessing but it keeps crashing for odd reasons. Numpy arrays is also another way to go, thanks marscher

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking into splitting computation across processes, I would strongly recommend giving the "multiprocessing" module a read which has concepts like process pools, managers and ability to share high-level data structures across process boundaries. For e.g. take a look at ["sharing state between two processes"](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) section in the docs. From the docs:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array

def f(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(arr,))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(arr[:])

#output: [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```